# Calling external php script from html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, apache2

This is my first post so I apologize if this is in the wrong area or not in the correct format!

I am extremely new to web development and wasn't able to find what I am looking for, so I figured I would ask here. My desire is to create a web server on my Raspberry Pi that contains an HTML webpage. When a button is clicked in the HTML page, a Javascript script at the bottom of the HTML page is called to get text from a textbox and validate it. I then want to send this data to a PHP script (located in the same directory as the index.html file) which solely executes another python script with the data located on my Pi. When I run my PHP script from the terminal as so:

```
sudo php setalarm.php "10 20 1,2,3"
```

it functions as expected, but upon clicking the button on the HTML page, nothing happens. I have verified that the "package" variable contains the proper data, but I am unable to see the results of the JQuery.

I have the following questions:

1. If my only desire is to send the "package" (see the HTML File Snippet - Message Javascript, line 2 below or the second argument in the command above) as a command line argument to execute a python script from my HTML page, is this the correct way to do so? If not, how can I perform such a task?
2. Is there a way to debug and view my external PHP file from the HTML page? I am using IE's debugging tools and if I set a breakpoint immediately before my jQuery and step into the next line, I am unable to view the PHP script, just a blank return result.
3. If the method I am trying is a good way to go about it, are there any obvious errors or issues you see with the code?

**EDIT - New PHP Script**

```
<?php
echo "Package is: " . $_GET['package'];
system("sudo python /home/pi/Alarm/change_alarm.py {$_GET['package']}", $ret_val);
?>
```

**HTML File Snippet - Button**

```
<div class="grid8 a-right">
    <form method="post"> </form>
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" onclick="message()"> SET</button>
</div>
```

**HTML File Snippet - Message Javascript**

```
alert("Alarm set for " + hour + ":" + minute + " on " + message);
package = hour + " " + minute + " " + list;

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "setalarm.php",
  data: { package: package }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert(msg);
});
```

Thank you all very much for your help! Again, I apologize if I made any mistakes in this post. Also, as mentioned before, I am very new to web development so this is probably a very silly mistake. I am sorry if that is indeed the case!

Comment: if you're putting an array value in a double quoted string, you have to wrap it in curly-braces like `system("sudo python /home/pi/Alarm/change_alarm.py {$argv[1]}", $ret_val);`

Comment: AJAX parameters aren't in `$argv`. Use `$_GET['package']`

Comment: Thank you both for your prompt responses!
@Barmar just to make sure I understand, are you suggesting I change the "$argv[1]" in my PHP file to "$_GET['package']" ? Or did I misinterpret you?

Thanks again!

Comment: @clark173 you pass data: `data: { package: package }`, therefor in PHP, it would be in the `$_GET` global, under they index 'package'. So yes, to get that value, call `$_GET['package']` in `setalarm.php`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately, I still don't believe the PHP script is being executed as I added a simple line that writes the inputs to a text file in the first line of the PHP. Is there a way I can see if the PHP script is being executed or if there are any errors?

Comment: Well to make sure your PHP script is firing you can just echo some test content and if it gets returned in your AJAX alert then you know the PHP script is firing

Comment: Alright, I just confirmed that the PHP script is firing as I got the proper return results in the AJAX alert when I echoed text in the PHP script. However, when I do `echo "$_GET['package']"; ` the alert does not show. Do you know why this could be? Is there some error with using this method to get the package?

Comment: What do you see if you do `echo "Package is: " . $_GET['package'];`? Do you see the first part followed by a blank value?

Comment: @Barmar, when I do echo the above, I get the proper package as the message, so it looks like it is receiving the package correctly. But my python script is still not being called. Do I need to change the system command? Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe there's a permissions problem -- is  `/home/pi/Alarm/change_alarm.py` world-readable, and are all the directories leading to it world-readable and world-executable? Or maybe `python` isn't in the web server's `$PATH`.

Comment: `change_alarm.py` as well as all of the parent directories are readable and executable. They all are owned by the `pi` user as well. Is there an issue with the fact that my python script I am trying to execute isn't in the same location as the web server? And I followed the instructions at [this link](http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/129-servers/757148-configuring-apache2-to-run-python-scripts), is that what you are referring to for adding `python` to my `$PATH`?

Comment: For the `system` command in my PHP code, for `$ret_val` I keep getting a `1`. Is there any way I can debug this and see why I am receiving this return code? Thanks again.

Comment: Just wanted to let everyone know that I fixed my issue! I will edit my question later, but basically I forgot to give my `www-data` user (the user for the web server) sudoers permission and I also moved the python script to my `var/www` folder and changed the php script accordingly. These changes fixed the problem. Thank you everyone for all of the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the problem, I had to make a few changes to my webserver. First, I noticed in my error log found at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` that it was missing a favicon, so I created a simple one using PhotoShop. Second, I added my apache2 user account, `www-data` to sudo and gave it all permissions. Third, I moved my python script to the `/var/www/` folder where my webserver is located and updated the php script accordingly. The three above combined to fix my problem.